# REST POST create multiple domain objects at once?

Tags: rest, grails

I have quickly managed to get domain classes to be created via a REST POST, but am stuck on how to create multiple creates for a xml file with multiple objects of the same type in, eg where as I was successful with

```
<Track>
       <trackAlbumName> Songs for Polar Bears </trackAlbumName>
       <trackArtistName> Snow PAtrol </trackArtistName>
       <trackSongTitle> First Song </trackSongTitle>
</Track>
```

I have added a UploadTrackGroup domain class, and now wish to create multiple Track objects in the same upload, eg I was hoping to POST something like;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<UploadTrackGroup>

    <Track>
       <trackAlbumName> Songs for Polar Bears </trackAlbumName>
       <trackArtistName> Snow PAtrol </trackArtistName>
       <trackSongTitle> First Song </trackSongTitle>
    </Track>

    <Track>
       <trackAlbumName> Different Class </trackAlbumName>
       <trackArtistName> Pulp </trackArtistName>
       <trackSongTitle> Misshapes </trackSongTitle>
    </Track>

    <Track>
       <trackAlbumName> F Sharp A Sharp </trackAlbumName>
       <trackArtistName> Godspeed You Black Emperor </trackArtistName>
       <trackSongTitle> Dead Flag BLues</trackSongTitle>
    </Track>

</UploadTrackGroup>
```

But I'll be damned if I can get it to work.

When I try to use the following code in my controller;

```
println params

params.UploadTrackGroup.each {
    println "-->" + it
}
```

I only see a single track, eg

```
[action:create, controller:recognisedSong, UploadTrackGroup:[Track: F Sharp A Sharp  Godspeed You Black Emperor  Dead Flag BLues]]

-->Track= F Sharp A Sharp  Godspeed You Black Emperor  Dead Flag BLues
```

Comment: where are you having the problem?  in the client? on the server? where.  Details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was successful in achieving what I wanted by effectively ignoring the parent UploadTrackGroup node, and simply using

```
 request.XML.Track.each { 
                  println it.trackAlbumName.text() + " " + it.trackArtistName.text()
              }
```

It would appear that as soon as I try to specify the exact qualified path to the Track nodes, ie `UploadTrackGroup.Track.each` or various variations thereof, it doesnt work.

So it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def xml = request.XML
int tracksSize = xml.UploadTrackGroup[0].Track.size()
if (trackSize > 0) {
  def trackGroupXml = xml.UploadTrackGroup[0]
  for (int i = 0; i < tracksSize; ++i) {
    def albumName= x.Track[i].trackAlbumName.text()
    //Get other props out of XML, create domain object
  }
}
```

You may also want to name your controller with "RestController".  See [this about controllers](http://www.grails.org/New+Controller+Types).

Comment: That doesnt seem to work. Do I need to create a UploadTrackGroup domain object in order for this to work? Would the contents of this be a hasMany tracks map?

Comment: What if you println request.xml?  Do you see all 3 of your <Track> elements?  (the element names will not print, but the values are there.)  Also, you should not need a domain object for UploadTrackGroup.